# How to convert website content to CSV (python)?

Tags: python, csv

I am retrieving some data from a website and taking a look at the text to double check if I am getting the correct data as per below (there is some code before this but just trying to simplify the question).

```
response = requests.post('https://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/wwv_flow.accept', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
soup.text
```

soup.text returns the following text:

```
'Tesouro Nacional (National Treasury)\r\nTipo de leilão: Venda (Auction type)\r\nTipo de título: LTN (Title Type)\r\nData inicial do leilão: 01/01/2021 (Auction start date)\r\nData final do leilão: 18/01/2021 (Auction end date)\r\n\r\n* TROCA = Exchange Auction / VENDA = Sale Auction / COMPRA = Purchase Auction / EXTRA COMPRA = Extraordinary Purchase Auction / EXTRA VENDA = Extraordinary Sale Auction\r\nData do leilão;Título;Tipo de leilão;Volta;Data de liquidação;Data de vencimento;Oferta;Taxa média;Taxa de corte;Venda;Financeiro (R$);Venda para Bacen;Financeiro para Bacen (R$)\r\nAuction Date;Bond Type;Auction Type;Round;Settlement Date;Maturity Date;Quantity Tendered;Average Rate;Accepted Rate;Quantity Accepted;Total Amount Accepted (R$);Quantity to Central Bank;Total Amount to Central Bank (R$)\r\n14/01/2021;LTN;Venda;1.ª volta;15/01/2021;01/01/2023;7.000.000;5,2529;5,2580;7.000.000;6.332.858.153,49;16.500.000;14.927.451.363,00\r\n14/01/2021;LTN;Venda;2.ª volta;18/01/2021;01/01/2023;1.400.000;5,2529;5,2529;126.363;114.343.255,15;0;0,00\r\n14/01/2021;LTN;Venda;1.ª volta;15/01/2021;01/07/2024;3.000.000;6,5683;6,5700;3.000.000;2.410.886.792,00;18.600.000;14.947.498.116,60\r\n14/01/2021;LTN;Venda;2.ª volta;18/01/2021;01/07/2024;600.000;6,5683;6,5683;338.181;271.840.942,59;0;0,00\r\n14/01/2021;LTN;Venda;1.ª volta;15/01/2021;01/10/2021;15.000.000;2,9027;2,9039;15.000.000;14.698.203.631,45;0;0,00\r\n14/01/2021;LTN;Venda;2.ª volta;18/01/2021;01/10/2021;3.000.000;2,9027;2,9027;243.636;238.761.237,59;0;0,00\r\n07/01/2021;LTN;Venda;1.ª volta;08/01/2021;01/01/2023;5.000.000;4,6749;4,6898;4.800.000;4.385.591.302,37;0;0,00\r\n07/01/2021;LTN;Venda;2.ª volta;11/01/2021;01/01/2023;1.000.000;4,6749;4,6749;0;0,00;0;0,00\r\n07/01/2021;LTN;Venda;1.ª volta;08/01/2021;01/04/2022;10.000.000;3,5466;3,5624;10.000.000;9.581.654.056,22;0;0,00\r\n07/01/2021;LTN;Venda;2.ª volta;11/01/2021;01/04/2022;2.000.000;3,5466;3,5466;0;0,00;0;0,00\r\n07/01/2021;LTN;Venda;1.ª volta;08/01/2021;01/07/2024;2.500.000;6,0619;6,0798;2.032.000;1.657.984.532,52;0;0,00\r\n07/01/2021;LTN;Venda;2.ª volta;11/01/2021;01/07/2024;500.000;6,0619;6,0619;0;0,00;0;0,00\r\n'
```

Which kind of looks like a CSV. However, when I try to convert it to a CSV file doing the following, I get an error saying "teste_tesouro.csv is not UTF-8 encoded"

```
csv = open('teste_tesouro.csv', 'wb')
csv.write(response.content)
csv.close()
```

How can I properly convert that data to a CSV file?

Thanks!

Comment: as you may know, csv mean that the file will have separated fields. what would these fields be for you data? i would start by figuring out what data you need from the content

Comment: I am confused. `response.content` is a byte string and your have opened the file in binary mode. Thus, I would think that no encoding would be involved. So how is it possible that those 3 lines produce the error you say you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not quite sure if this can work for you my friend but you can try it

first i'd try this

```
response.to_csv('name of your final ', sep = '\', encoding='latin-1',)
```

the encondig part is not really necessary but since I see you are brazilian like me this gave me some problems in the past so specifying the encoding may help

also, I've never used \ as a separator, so no idea what will be the outcome, if it doesn't work try replacing it for ; and puting ; as a sep that it should work

Comment: made a few tweaks on this it worked. thanks a lot!